# Inserting shortcode in a PHP file in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I've using the collapse-o-matic and I'can't figure out how to pass a field into it.

The shortcode is:

```
echo do_shortcode('[expand title="Click here"]Hidden text. [/expand]');
```

Instead of `Hidden text` I want to pass the field which I would usually get by using this:

```
get_custom_field('description', true);
```

It appears I can't just copy and paste this snippet into the relevant bit.

How can I achieve what I'm after?

Comment: Can you share how you tried to copy and paste the snippet into the relevant part?

Comment: <?php echo do_shortcode('[expand title="click here "] <?php get_custom_field('description', true); ?>
<hr> [/expand]'); ?>

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make your `do_shortcode` call dynamic, but you have to pass the entire content of the shortcode into the `do_shortcode` function call, and it's hard to tell from your comment how that line is actually structured.  Try this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[expand title="click here "] ' . get_custom_field('description', true) . ' <hr> [/expand]'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  Its not quite worked.  It's picked up the field now but it's displaying  I can I think its not processing the end tag [/expand] correctly

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  Its nearly worked.  It's picking up the field now, but it's on display rather then hidden.  I don't think that the final tag [/expand] is being picked up correctly.